# Share APK via Azure DevOps public link

Tags: android, azure-devops, xamarin.android, azure-pipelines, devops

I have setup Azure DevOps CI/CD in my project. I want to share APK artifact to someone else via public link. Via artifact link, it requires credentials.
Anyone has any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a public feed by going to the Artifacts tab in a public project and clicking **+ New Public Feed** near the top of the UI. All packages stored in the public feed can be accessed by anyone by following the steps in the **Connect to feed** dialog. Anonymous access is read-only, and users still need to the correct permissions in order to push new packages to public feeds.

[image]

**Note:** The first 2 GB of public packages are free, just like with private Azure Artifacts feeds.

To learn more about public feeds, check out our [feeds documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/concepts/feeds?view=azure-devops), or if you want to dive in, go straight to our [tutorial on sharing packages publicly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/tutorials/share-packages-publicly?view=azure-devops).

Comment: I believe, this is for package (like Nuget etc..) Is it possible to share file from drop folder publically?